# LoginController redirectTo

Tags: laravel

in my `LoginController`,

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

but I completely ignore `HomeController` and I used all the codes in `ProfileController`. Actually, after I logged in I have to display the index page. I can bypass this by `URL` but in actual login I have setup some authentication.

`Logintroller.php`

```php
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

`web.php`

```php
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profiles.show');
```

when my URL is, `123.0.0.1:8000/home`
I get

404
Not Found

I have changed my `path` as `123.0.0.1:8000/profile`
even now it hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

In your web.php  add

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
   return view('welcome');
})
```

Or send it anywhere you want.

Comment: How can I redirect to a particular page after login. In my LoginController it is redirected to home. But I need to change that and I changed it but URL says not found.  I think the problem is there is no user ID after the path I have changed. So my question is is this possible to pass user ID in LoginController in the following         protected $redirected =/profile/{$user->id}.           I am using laravel6. Please help..

Comment: In your Controller, define a `redirectTo ` method  and comment out the $redirectTo  part.

Since that is called once the user's been authenticated successfully, you can do something like:

`public function redirectTo(){

return redirect 'profile/'.Auth()->user()->id;

}`

Comment: public function redirectTo()
    {
        return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user->id); 
    }                                                                                                                                I used like above but it gives me the following error                                                     Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user

Comment: Alternatively, there is a better solution to use the "authenticated" method, that runs when the user has successfully been logged in, but before they are redirected. So, something like 

    public function authenticated(){
       
       return redirect 'profile/'.Auth()->user()->id; 
    }